# Cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment)' in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am unable to resolve this error since few days.

It's in ScanActivity.java

This is the code:

```
private void init() {
        PickImageFragment fragment = new PickImageFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ScanConstants.OPEN_INTENT_PREFERENCE, getPreferenceContent());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Getting error from here `(R.id.content, fragment)`

Imported this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.ComponentCallbacks2;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.Fade;
import android.view.Window;
```

Whenever I use "Migrate to AppCompat" The error goes, but then two errors occurs simultaneously in other files, ResultFragment.java and ScanFragment.java.

What should I do?

Edit:
I already tried to change to androidx.fragment.app.________ through 'Migrate to AppCompat', but when this error is resolved, 2 more errors come through in the above mentioned files on same piece of code:

```
protected void showProgressDialog(String message) {
        progressDialogFragment = new ProgressDialogFragment(message);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        progressDialogFragment.show(fm, ProgressDialogFragment.class.toString());
    }
```

This is the error: Cannot resolve method 'show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)'

in the line: `progressDialogFragment.show(fm, ProgressDialogFragment.class.toString());`

imported in these files

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
```

(source code acquired from Github https://github.com/clean-apps/CleanSCAN, Just changed name, migrated it to AndroidX, and upgraded depracated libraries and codes)

Answer (score 0):

Change your import from `android` to `androidx` like :

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Changes to :

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: I had tried it, but didn't worked
Used 'Migrate to AppCompat' to do it, and error would be gone, but as I wrote, it shows error in both above mentioned files on the same piece of code:                         

```protected void showProgressDialog(String message) {
        progressDialogFragment = new ProgressDialogFragment(message);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        progressDialogFragment.show(fm, ProgressDialogFragment.class.toString());
    }
```
The error is: Cannot resolve method 'show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)'